# Compiled exe needs to be run as admin but uncompiled py file doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller

I recently compiled a python project I have been working on for some time to an exe, only to find you'd need to run it as an administrator for it to work, despite it not requiring any elevation while it was simply a .py file. It returns an internal error "cannot create temporary directory!" if you don't run it with elevation. I presume this has to do something with the program reading/writing to the users appdata/locallow folder (it stores some of it's files in there). Is there a simple fix to this? I'd much prefer it if the apps files could remain in one of the appdata folders whether it be local, locallow or roaming.

This can be reproduced by following these steps:

1. create a main.py file with the following code inside:

```
    import os, json
    
    LOG_DIR = os.path.expanduser('~\AppData\Locallow\AppName\logs')
    LOG_PATH = os.path.expanduser('~\AppData\Locallow\AppName\logs\log.txt')
    
    PREFS_DIR = os.path.expanduser('~\AppData\Locallow\AppName\prefs')
    PREFS_PATH = os.path.expanduser('~\AppData\Locallow\AppName\prefs\prefs.json')
    
    user_prefs = None
    
    def log_init():
        if os.path.isfile(LOG_PATH):
            with open(LOG_PATH, 'a') as f:
                f.close()
        else:
            if not os.path.isdir(LOG_DIR):
                os.mkdir(LOG_DIR)
            
            with open(LOG_PATH, 'w') as f:
                f.close()
    
    def prefs_init():
        global user_prefs
        if os.path.isfile(PREFS_PATH):
            user_prefs = json.load(open(PREFS_PATH, 'r'))
        else:
            if not os.path.isdir(PREFS_DIR):
                os.mkdir(PREFS_DIR)
            
            with open(PREFS_PATH, 'w') as f:
                f.write('{"welc_msg": "DirNav - The all in one file browser and terminal!", "file_color": {}}')
                f.close()
            
            user_prefs = json.load(open(PREFS_PATH, 'r'))
    
    log_init()
    prefs_init()
```

2. Make the following folder: C:/Users/YOUR_USER/AppData/Locallow/AppName
3. Running main.py will generate 'prefs' and 'logs' with respective files inside.
4. Delete 'prefs' and 'logs'
5. Compile main.py using this command: pyinstaller -F main.py
6. Running the new .exe that is in the 'dist' folder from cmd will result in an 'INTERNAL ERROR: cannot create temporary directory!' message.
7. Run the .exe again but this time run as an administrator and it will work perfectly fine

The main premise here is why does the executable need to be run as an admin yet the .py file doesn't? And how do I make it so the executable doesn't need to be run as an admin?

Comment: The problem seems to be when pyinstaller bootloader is trying to create the _MEIxxxxxx folder in you temporary files location. Check permissions on %temp%

Comment: @EricMathieu I'm a bit uneducated, could you explain how to do that and what I'm looking for? I can freely add and delete files in there if that's what you meant

Comment: Open a cmd window and type "echo %temp%". With the file explorer browse to locate this folder (you may have to select the hidden element option), display the folder properties and review the security tab

Comment: @EricMathieu everything is checked for 'allow' aside from special permissions, which I cannot change.

Comment: Do you have enough disk space ? Is you program using special libraries ?

Comment: @EricMathieu I have 550GB free space and I am using the following modules: os, DirNav, sys, colorama, logging, shutil, json, time, traceback, re, colorama, distutils.dir_util

Comment: I am running out of idea. It could be good if you provide a Minimal Reproductible Exemple (MRE) so that we can progress (i.e. the smallest possible program that reproduce the issue)

Comment: @EricMathieu I believe I already gave a MRE after I explained the issue. Follow steps 1-7 and it should replicate the issue

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue on my computer with your code. Anyway I am still pretty sure there is an issue with your temp directory. Can you build your example adding --runtime-tmpdir a_folder_you_know _for_sure_is_yours. See https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#how-the-one-file-program-works for explanation

Comment: Now it just has a popup saying "Internal Error: Cannot create temporary directory!" at this point I'd just give up with it. Clearly it's just not happy with it, not sure why but these things happen I guess. It was just a project to help make CMD more user friendly so nothing too important anyway.